# Find the role arn by inputing role name prefix in Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

First of all, this is the requirement for a part of the terraform module I am working on.

On my multiple AWS accounts, I would like to get the ARN of the role name starting with the name **AWSReservedSSO_AdministratorAccess** as originally it looks like **AWSReservedSSO_AdministratorAccess_{{XXAccountIdNumber}}** and the portion {{XXAccountIdNumber}} varies to each AWS account.

If I had known the fixed name, I would have tried as follows:

```
data "aws_iam_role" "example_role" {
  name = "AWSReservedSSO_AdministratorAccess_a88e813xf3c99999"
}

output "role_arn" {
  value = data.aws_iam_role.example_role.arn
}
```

and it would output like this:

```
Outputs:

role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::1234567891055:role/aws-reserved/sso.amazonaws.com/eu-west-1/AWSReservedSSO_AdministratorAccess_a88e813xf3c99999"
```

Any idea how to do this if we want to use only the name prefix like **AWSReservedSSO_AdministratorAccess**?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the answer now.

Use [Data Source: aws_iam_role](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_role) if you know the specific role name already

and use [Data Source: aws_iam_roles](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/-/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_roles) which provides the feature to find roles filtered by name regex.

With that said, I use this example to get it:

```
data "aws_iam_roles" "example_role" {
  name_regex = "AWSReservedSSO_AdministratorAccess.*"
}

output "role_arns" {
  value = data.aws_iam_roles.example_role.arns
}
```

You will get the output like:

Outputs:

```
role_arns = toset([
  "arn:aws:iam::1234567891055:role/aws-reserved/sso.amazonaws.com/eu-west-1/AWSReservedSSO_AdministratorAccess_a88e813xf3c99999",
])
```

Comment: I came here for exactly the same thing - how to find the IAM Role created by the IAM Identity Center :)